# Android Handle phone call

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I have audio recording, when a phone call come I need to stop the recording, how can I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to use the `PhoneStateListener`:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
tm.listen(mPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

// somewhere else
private PhoneStateListener mPhoneListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        try {
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                // do something...
                break;

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                // do something...
                break;

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                // do something...
                break;
            default:
                Log.d(TAG, "Unknown phone state=" + state);
            }
        } catch (RemoteException e) {}
    } 
};
```

Make sure to include this permission in your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried to access the phone stuff on Android but check here -

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/package-summary.html

and here -

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html

and here -

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html