# How to get cell information of call received in android?

Tags: android, incoming-call

I want get cell information (name of cell and address of cell) of incoming call in android?
Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Handle phone call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324659/android-handle-phone-call)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, if the information are stored in your device phonebook.  You can use PhoneStateListener to detected Phone call State.

[Here more information](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html)

Comment: Explain and give an example to be more. please